# How to separate indepedent selection to multiple layers in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, image-sprites

I found a [picture that contains a lot of of sprites](http://godofdarness18.deviantart.com/art/Pixel-Sprite-Montage-Last-Updated-Jan-22-2016-405729921) and I would like to divide it into separate layers to use it in my video game (after asking permission from the owner).

To do so I have to create a layer for each sprite and I've already selected each sprite so it look like this:

[image: Clean sprites' picture]

I wonder how to separate each selected sprite into multiple layers. I've already searched and I found [this](https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/feature_request_quick_way_to_make_multiple_layers_from_inversely_selected_objects), but the link to the script is dead (404).

I'm not very familiar with Photoshop, but I can do basic things on it, so I don't know if there is a simple way to do it.

Comment: Why you don't use a video game icon libary?

Comment: Because I want these ones, and because I've already envisage the other solutions, so I just want to know how to do it on Photoshop